# Springboot process keeps running even after completion in batch mode

Tags: java, spring-boot

I need to run the springboot application in the batch mode. As soon as the processes get finished, the process should exit. I have written a mock code to achieve the same but even after the print statement is completed, the process is not getting completed and I have to manually abort the process.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        Test test = applicationContext.getBean(Test.class);
        test.printTest();
    }

}
```

***Test.class :***

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Test{

    public void printTest(){
        System.out.println("Test class !");
    }

}
```

***Dependencies :***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It keeps running because you are using an ApplicationContext. You should close the context.
You can use ConfigurableApplicationContext and call the close() method .

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        Test test = applicationContext.getBean(Test.class);
        test.printTest();
        applicationContext.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application keeps running because it is configured as a Web server. If you want to run it as a *one off* application you should remove the `spring-boot-starter-web` from `pom.xml`.